# How do i pass ## separated values in Scala?

Tags: scala, gatling

Consider the following scenario:

```
["123##456","789##101112","131415##161718","192021##222324"]
```

first-id: `123`, second-id: `456`...

I get the above as two different sets of ids in the JSON payload of my response.

Saving the values via

```
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].Id").findAll.saveAs("Id"))
```

works perfectly fine for me.

But now I need to pass the above-mentioned ids in the next request of post method, which comes as

```
["123##456","789##101112","131415##161718","192021##222324"]
```

So how to achieve that? If you could explain with an example please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split`, something like:

```
var data = Array("123##456","789##101112","131415##161718","192021##222324");

for(i <- 0 until data.length){
    var ids = data(i).split("##");
    println("first id is: " + ids(0));
    println("second id is: " + ids(1));
}
```